# Update random number mySQL

Tags: mysql

Please help me.

I have:

```
SELECT *  FROM `Homepage`.`wp_postmeta` 
WHERE (CONVERT(`meta_id` USING utf8) LIKE '%like%'
OR CONVERT(`post_id` USING utf8) LIKE '%like%'
OR CONVERT(`meta_key` USING utf8) LIKE '%like%'
OR CONVERT(`meta_value` USING utf8) LIKE '%like%')
ORDER BY `post_id` DESC
```

So i want to update random number for meta_value (of meta_key is like_key)
i submit:

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta
SET meta_value = abs(checksum(NewId()) % 1000)+ 1000
WHERE meta_key LIKE '%like_key%'
```

but it not working, it say:

> MySQL said: Documentation
>
> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '(NewId()) % 1000)+ 1000 WHERE meta_key LIKE '%like_key%'' at
>   line 1

please help me, i thank you very much

Comment: what is `NewId()`

Comment: What is `checksum()` ?

Answer (score 1):

The following query should do what you want on MariaDB:

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta
SET meta_value = (RAND()*1000) + 1000
WHERE meta_key LIKE '%like_key%'
```

This will update the `meta_value` for those matching rows to some number between `1000` and `2000`, which is what your current attempt implies.